# Make GIF element in Shortcuts crashes shortcut

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I’ve created a shortcut which should make GIF out of burst image but when I run a shortcut it crashes and doesn’t make GIF. Has anyone had the same problem?
Here’s how my shortcut looks like:

[image: Make GIG shortcut]

iOS 12.4 / iPhone X

Comment: Ok, updated it to 0,2 seconds and turned infinite loop off, still same result.

Comment: Try to get images using the photos *API* (I know it's a heavy word). and then pass it to the GIF making. See the shortcut I shared below.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like description of element “Get frames from image” is inaccurate in stating that it handles burst images. When I get different element which loads only latest burst the shortcut works properly with any setting in GIF conversion element.

Comment: How did you get the statement "this Shortcut accepts images" Can you share the shortcut ?

Comment: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/8340fd4ea7864b12a20a87023edfad70 the works fine for me

Comment: @ankiiiiiii click on toggles on top right at the screen and then you’ll see a menu item where you can choose which types of files shortcut will accept.